FFmpeg decoding h265 yuv422p10 returns Failed setup for format Vulkan: hwaccel initialisation errorer
I try to test h265 10-bit yuv422p10le decoding according to test command at
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#Vulkan
ffmpeg -init_hw_device "vulkan=vk:0" -hwaccel vulkan -hwaccel_output_format vulkan -i INPUT -f null - -benchmark
but get the following output error:
[hevc @ 0x5580e96e8c80] Failed setup for format vulkan: hwaccel initialisation returned error.

See full output below.
(In comparison ffmpeg vulkan decoding a h264 8-bit yuv420p works without error)
Is it possible to query and verify if "yuv422p10le" is a Vulkan supported pixel format?
I tried for example this command, but got no hit at all:
vulkaninfo --show-formats | grep yuv42
This is on a workstation as follows:
inxi -CGS
System:
  Host: localhost.localdomain Kernel: 6.10.5-1-default arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.3.1 Distro: openSUSE Tumbleweed-Slowroll 20240803
CPU:
  Info: 12-core (8-mt/4-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700KF bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP cache: L2: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 886 min/max: 800/4900:5000:3800 cores: 1: 800 2: 800
    3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 2524 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800
    13: 800 14: 800 15: 800 16: 800 17: 800 18: 800 19: 800 20: 800
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel DG2 [Arc A750] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Microdia Camera driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.12 with: Xwayland v: 24.1.1 driver:
    X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.1.5 renderer: Mesa Intel Arc
    A750 Graphics (DG2)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.290 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib
  API: EGL Message: EGL data requires eglinfo. Check --recommends.


ffmpeg -hide_banner -init_hw_device "vulkan=vk:0" -hwaccel vulkan -hwaccel_output_format vulkan -i h265_yuv422p10le_SR.mp4 -f null - -benchmark
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'h265_yuv422p10le_SR.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Duration: 00:01:11.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2703 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Rext) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv422p10le(pc, smpte170m/unknown/unknown, top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2700 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
** [hevc @ 0x55edf209fa40] Failed setup for format vulkan: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
** [hevc @ 0x55edf209fa40] Unsupported film grain parameters. Ignoring film grain.
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv422p10le(pc, smpte170m/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 wrapped_avframe
[out#0/null @ 0x55edf207ff40] video:764KiB audio:0KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: unknown
frame= 1779 fps=750 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:11.16 bitrate=N/A speed=  30x    
bench: utime=15.892s stime=0.188s rtime=2.371s
bench: maxrss=411104KiB

